# Automate configuration options for github install with renv

Tags: r, renv

I am trying to include a development version package in a project with renv. However the package requires the following install options

```
install_github("james-thorson/VAST", INSTALL_opts="--no-staged-install")
```

I see in the `renv` documentation that it is possible to supply configuration options to the install

https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/install.html#package-configuration

But I'm unclear how and where to include this option so that it is reproducible by other users

1. How exactly would I pass the `--no-staged-install` to renv within an renv environment

```
configure.args = c(VAST = "install_opts=--no-staged-install")
options(configure.args = configure.args)
renv::install("james-thorson/VAST")
```

doesn't seem to work, neither does

```
options(install.opts = "--no-staged-install")
renv::install("james-thorson/VAST")
```

2. Where would I then put those instructions so that when new users try and restore the repo the VAST install instructions are followed? In the .Rprofile file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renv` uses an option called `install.opts` for this case. From `?renv::install`:

> Similarly, additional flags that should be passed to R CMD INSTALL can
> be set via the install.opts R option:
>
> ```
> # installation of R packages using the Windows Subsystem for Linux
> # may require the `--no-lock` flag to be set during install
> options(install.opts = "--no-lock")
> renv::install("xml2")
> ```

In this case, I believe you can set:

```
options(install.opts = "--no-staged-install")
renv::install("james-thorson/VAST")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before with no luck but it seems to be working now on mac but not on linux, figures! My question then though is where would I specify that option so that it works for other users? i.e. when another collaborator clones the repository, and then runs `renv::restore()` to install dependencies, where in the project would I specify options(install.opts = "--no-staged-install") so that the user themselves doesn't have to enter it? And would putting it in say the .Rprofile then affect the install process of other packages that might not need that option?

Comment: This isn't documented, but you can place an R script at `<project>/renv/settings.R`, and that script will be sourced by `renv` whenever the project is loaded. (Or, you can also just place it directly in the project `.Rprofile` as well.)